# Transaction failing with "range end index out of range"

Tags: anchor, web3.js, rust

I'm calling a function of Marinade's program `MarBmsSgKXdrN1egZf5sqe1TMai9K1rChYNDJgjq7aD`. The function name is `orderUnstake`. I'm forming the Tx as follows

```
    const txSign = await program.methods.orderUnstake(value)
    .accounts(
        {
            state: statePublicKey,
            msolMint: msolMintPublicKey,
            burnMsolFrom: burnMsolFromPubKey,
            burnMsolAuthority: baseAccount.publicKey,
            newTicketAccount: newAccountPubkey,
            clock: SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
            rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        }
    )
    .signers([baseAccount])
    .rpc();
```

and passing the value as a BigNumber.

The error I'm receiving is

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/namanmanchanda/Desktop/backend/investment-service/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4594:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/namanmanchanda/Desktop/backend/investment-service/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4553:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/namanmanchanda/Desktop/backend/investment-service/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:288:21)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/Users/namanmanchanda/Desktop/backend/investment-service/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:148:14)
    at async Object.rpc [as orderUnstake] (/Users/namanmanchanda/Desktop/backend/investment-service/node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16) {
  logs: [
    'Program MarBmsSgKXdrN1egZf5sqe1TMai9K1rChYNDJgjq7aD invoke [1]',
    'Program log: libstd rust_begin_panic',
    "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 8 out of range for slice of length 0', programs/marinade-finance/src/lib.rs:607:10",
    'Program MarBmsSgKXdrN1egZf5sqe1TMai9K1rChYNDJgjq7aD consumed 12667 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: BPF program panicked',
    'Program MarBmsSgKXdrN1egZf5sqe1TMai9K1rChYNDJgjq7aD failed: Program failed to complete'
  ],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack { stack: [ [PublicKey] ] }
}
```

Comment: Error happened during program executaion. You can see the error in the logs: `range end index 8 out of range for slice of length 0', programs/marinade-finance/src/lib.rs:607:10`

Comment: "range end index 8 out of range for slice of length 0" looks like Anchor trying to get account sha and instead getting an empty account.
Q1: Is this mainnet or testnet?
Q2: What is the value for `state` (pubkey)
Q3: newAccountPubkey is an account you've just created with the *right size* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the error looks like you might be creating it with size = 0

your code should look like this:

```
  // new random keypair
  const newTicketAccount = new Keypair();
  const ticketAccountSize = 8 + 32 + 32 + 8 + 8;

  tx.add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: walletPubKey as PublicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: newTicketAccount.publicKey,
      lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
        ticketAccountSize
      ),
      space: ticketAccountSize,
      programId: keys.marinadeProgramId,
    })
  );

  tx.add(
    program?.instruction.orderUnstake(new BN(stSolAmountLamports), {
      accounts: {
        state: keys.marinadeStateId,
        stSolMint: marinadeState?.state.st_sol_mint.value as Address,

        burnStSolFrom: userStSOLAccountAddress as Address,
        burnStSolAuthority: walletPubKey as Address,

        newTicketAccount: newTicketAccount.publicKey,

        clock: SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
        rent: SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      },
    })
  );
```